# Programmatically determine if java code uses packages

Tags: java

I am expecting a Java code in response to my question in one application. On the back-end I run few tests on the code. Is it possible to somehow test programmatically if the submitted code contains "package" declaration? One way is to use RegEx on source for this, but we are trying to avoid it for various reasons.

Another way is to compile the code and check for existence of subdirectories and .class files in the directory - but that doesn't seem elegant either.

Is there a clean and elegant way to determine if the source code contains "package" declarations?

Add: We don't want packages in the code. So if someone adds them, we would like to detect and report error accordingly.

Comment: Your third option is to use a proper parser. I think that basically covers it: Using regex (problematic), compile it, or use a real parser.

Comment: You are expecting submission of Java code, but are not prepared to parse it to check that it is, in fact, Java code?

Comment: You could compile the Java code and run `javap` on the result. Strange requirement.